# generate IPA file using command line Mac book

Tags: ios, cross-platform, ipa

> i have developed an cordova project and wanted to generate a ipa file using command line, and not using xcode .
>
> This is what i have tried so far and i tried many links as well.

followed [this link](http://maruhgar.blogspot.in/2014/05/automating-cordova-ios-build.html)  `sudo cordova build ios --release` this build get successed,

Next step i tried this following comment `cordova build ios --device`  and get the below error :

```
Check dependencies Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.
```

i have done all the register process with Apple as well, could any one help me what needs to be done next step?

Comment: You need to set the Bundle Identifier properly, then use your Provisioning Profile and Certificate to sign the build. All of this needs to be set properly before building. Maybe you have to generate a separate AdHoc Distribution profile to build for test devices. Alternatively you can build and then re-sign the app with the correct provisioning. To do that from command line you could use [sigh](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh#resign)

Comment: @ast1 Thank u so much for the initial start, actully am an android developer, just today am starting the Ios to generate Ipa file using cross platform app, i have tried "sudo cordova build ios --device" this comment in command promit and got the following error : === BUILD TARGET Medlife MLDoctor OF PROJECT Medlife MLDoctor WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.

** BUILD FAILED *
The following build commands failed:
 Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for com

Comment: I recommend going through [this document](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps) as a starting point. It's important to see the general concept behind code signing, the process is not that straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i ll go through this, and update u

Comment: i have done the all the things in app store and i have the all the docs. but dont know how to go to fix this issue